# I want c++ generate random number is repeat

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I am two week newbie to programming in c++ but i am having challenge to get this code work as desired. my goal is to generate non repeated random number. Here is part of the code,

```
unsigned long seed = time(NULL);
int gsmNun (int l, int h)
{
    srand(seed);
    int user_phone = rand()%h+l;

    return user_phone;
}

int main()
{

    int z = gsmNun(70000000, 99999999);
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        cout << "the random number is!" << z << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `srand` every time you want to generate a random number but only once at the beginning of your program. (I'd stick to using a rng from `<random>` if possible.)

Comment: What's the question? How to make the non-repeated? Or why only one number is being printed? Because in the `for`, you print the same value for `z` 20 times. Maybe you want the definition of `z` and the `gsmNun` call to be inside the `for`?

Comment: Do you really want to print 20 lines containing the same "the random number is! somenumber" where somenumber does not change for all 20 iterations?

Comment: @ Kini kirov, the question is, how to make non-repeated number, thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reseeding the random number generator each time the function is called with the same seed, so you're always going to get the same random number from rand().

I've modified your code and added some comments, please note that you seed the random number generator once when the application starts and then calls to rand() will produce actual random numbers.

Reseeding your generator should not be done each time you want a new random number, as calls that are made too quickly will result in the same numbers being generated for those iterations.

```
unsigned long seed = time(NULL);
 int gsmNun (int l, int h)
 {
 // removed srand() from here.
 int user_phone = rand()%h+l;

 return user_phone;
 }

 int main()
 {

 srand(seed); // seed at application start
  for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {

 int z = gsmNun(70000000, 99999999);
    cout << "the random number is!" << z << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: He probably wants a new random number for each iteration as well, move the declaration of z inside the loop.

Comment: @dutt Example changed. Thank you for the correction! Not rightly sure how I missed that.